# How to automate desktop setup when starting up?

Tags: desktop, lxde, session, workspaces

I've set up my Linux laptop (running [Pixel for x86, based on Debian](https://www.raspberrypi.org/blog/pixel-pc-mac/)) to have three 'desktops'. I can access these with ctrl-alt-left and right.

1. Main - a blank desktop
2. CLI - a full screen, with no titlebar, LXTerminal
3. Browser - a full screen Chromium

If I restart the laptop, I still get 3 named 'desktops' but the Terminal and Browser are not open on desktops 2 and 3.

How do I get these apps to start in their appropriate desktop automatically upon startup?

Answer (score 1):

By 'desktops', I'm assuming you mean workspaces? Ctrl+alt+left/right are the shortcuts to switch between workspaces.

You could try using [`wmctrl`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/wmctrl) to launch certain programs in a specific workspace.

```
wmctrl -r <WINDOW NUMBER> -s <WORKSPACE NUMBER>
```

You would need to use `wmctrl -l` to find the window number:

```
0x0080006a -1 localhost panel
0x0180007c  0 localhost Chromium
0x02600007  3 localhost LXTerminal
```

And `wmctrl -d` to find the workspace number.

As for the automatic start-up, since this a command line tool, it can easily be ported to a simple shell script that is listed in your [autostart file](https://wiki.lxde.org/en/Autostart) (you can add it through the LXDE configuration interface).